# Check session object and return accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following code in my controller actions. I have more than 15 controllers and more than 40 actions through out the application. Example:

```cs
//Check if USER SESSION object is available
if (Session["user"] != null)
{
    return View();
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("logout", "Home", new { area = "Common", value = "SessionTimeOut" });
}
```

I don't want to repeat the if statement for all 40 actions. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: Even without getting the repeat-ability sorted, this would be already an improvement: `return Session["user"] != null ? View() : RedirectToAction("logout", "Home", new { area = "Common", value = "SessionTimeOut";`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at [AuthenticationFilters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) (see [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters) for an MVC walkthrough).

FTA:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext) {

        //For demo purpose only. In real life your custom principal might be retrieved via different source. i.e context/request etc.
        filterContext.Principal = new MyCustomPrincipal(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity, new []{"Admin"}, "Red");
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext) {
        var color = ((MyCustomPrincipal) filterContext.HttpContext.User).HairColor;
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

FTA usage:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //***here is where it's applied. you can also do this globally in Global.asax if preferred***
    [CustomAuthentication]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer pointing to the `[CustomAuthentication]` attribute, you could create a base controller class, like this:

```
[CustomAuthentication]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

Which your 15 controllers can inherit from:

```
public HomeController : BaseController
```

Now, by default, every action method on the derived controllers will execute the `[Authorize]` attribute, so for the action methods which do not require authorization, you can mark them with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP looks like an Authentication issue not Authorization.

Comment: I've replaced with `[CustomAuthentication]`, as the answer is the same really, to be consistent.